SDK issues in your latest production release: feature-delivery:2.0.1

com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.0.1 Google Play Feature
Delivery (com.google.android.play:feature-delivery) has added this
note for SDK version 2.0.1:
Update your Play Feature Delivery Maven dependency to an Android 14
compatible version! Your current Play Feature Delivery library is
incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a
backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers. As a reminder,
from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target
Android 14. Update to the latest library version dependency to avoid
app crashes:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#java-kotlin-feature-delivery
From 18 October 18, 2024 00:00 (UTC), you won't be able to release new
versions of your app containing this SDK version to production or open
testing

I dont have com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.0.1 at all in my application.
The only thing releated to this that i have is:
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'

// For Kotlin users also add the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Update:
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0'

Target SDK version:
targetSdkVersion 34

How can i fix this??

How about trying to add implementation 'com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.1.0' to your gradle file?

but why?? What ever that is.. i am not using it'

I don't think Google would complain if you are not using it, so my thought is that it is being used somewhere, even indirectly. So I thought if you added it explicitly to gradle, you might get some hints e.g. version conflicts and such (or at least make some progress over the current situation where you don't have any clue).

Or it would be better to see your app dependency tree by running ./gradlew app:dependencies so that where does feature-delivery come from.

If you use Google Nav Library -
Go to app gradle - change your nav library version from 2.7.7 to 2.8.0-beta06.
Go to the file -> project structure -> suggestions - warning magically gone.
So this warning is completely up to Google – or have this warning or use the beta version of the library.

I am facing same issue and your solution worked for me. Thanks @Nick :)

If you are using the navigation libraries, it will be a dependency. So it will be in there even though you can't see it.
Running ./gradlew app:dependencies will output your app dependencies, and you can expect to see something in there like:

So, yep, it's in the latest (as of August 2024) stable release of the android navigation libraries (v2.7.7). It's one of those "<provider> broke it but you have to fix it" things...
Solution:
Add the line(s)
implementation "com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.1.0", and/or
implementation "com.google.android.play:feature-delivery-ktx:2.1.0"
in your build.gradle near the implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$navx_version".
-or-
Replace nav v2.7.7 in vour build.gradle with v2.8.0-beta06 (note v2.8.0-beta07 requires API 35).
